# Set "Allow executing file as program" as default when files are added to a folder later

Tags: 14.04, permissions, python, executable, python-2.7

I have a folder, I am setting its permissions by using chmod.

```
chmod 777 /home/Desktop/Project
```

is success.

I am using a tool(.exe) that will download the project from the repository. But after the download completes all the subfolders and files under /home/Desktop/Project is having permissions as `drw-r--r--` and `-r--r--r--` respectively.

Is their any way I can set executable permissions for any files/folder under Project directory prior I start to download in Project Folder ?

**Note:** The entire processing is done using python script which uses the tool to download the project as said above. Testing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: ... create a script that does what this tool does and add a "chmod" on the next line. And "chmod 777" ... 755 is the most you *should* need for permissions. If you use 644 for files and 755 for dirs you will prevent yourself from using 777 on a file or dir that should *not* have these permissions

Comment: The same tool used for downloading also builds the project immediately after download completes, so I cannot set the permissions after download starts.

I need a ways as just before the download starts, I should be able to add files with "Allow executing file as program" as default for Project Directory.

Comment: The build tool should set the executable bit on the files that need it.  Otherwise I'll say it's a bug.

Comment: You're using a .exe?  From *Windows*?  If the thing is a Windows-based download manager or such, it won't 'work' with Linux filesystem permissions like you want it to.  Have you tried looking for a Linux-equivalent 'download and build' program?

Comment: The tool is build for linux too, I am using the linux version of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `man umask`. It says, in part:

```
trusty (1) umask.1posix.gz
Provided by: manpages-posix_2.16-1_all bug

NAME

       umask - get or set the file mode creation mask

SYNOPSIS

       umask [-S][mask]

DESCRIPTION

       The  umask utility shall set the file mode creation mask of the current
       shell execution environment (see Shell Execution Environment )  to  the
       value specified by the mask operand. This mask shall affect the initial
       value of the file permission bits of  subsequently  created  files.
```

What this means, is that when a file is created, it starts off assuming its permission wil be `777`, `rwxwrxwrx`, `Read, Write and Execute` access for `Owner`, `Group` and `World`. But then, the "mode bits" (another name for "permission  bits", but shorter) are ANDed with the COMPLIMENT of the `umask` value. If one sets `umask 022` (in `~/.bashrc`, or in the current shell, to affect that shell) then the operation is:

```
 777    Original mode bits  0B111111111
 755    Compliment of 022   0B111101101
-----   AND     
 755    The result, rwxr-xr-x (Read, Write, Execute for Owner, Read, Execute for Group and World
```

Another common `umask` value is `027` (NO access for World).

This is a tricky idea, and deserves understanding. I remember being confused for weeks about this back in the 1970s when I first ran into Unix.

Comment: I believe this is the only reason, 

While I created the directory I set its permissions (777) using os.system("chmod 777 <path>")
I am using python script, I used subprocess to start a new process (invokes the dowlnload/build tool).

I need to set umask for this subprocess right ? Cause it will be considered as a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to add that command to your `.bashrc` as function or alias, and execute that function or alias with `&&` operator.

In other words  `./pythonscript.py && aliasToChMod`